# Date not binding to input field in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using an `input` field of `type date` in my template which is the only form control(editable) inside a template driven form which in turn I'm using inside a `mat-table` in my Angular code. I'm using this table to display some records fetched from the server.

The date value is getting correctly populated from the service. However it doesn't bind to the date control. I expect it to show the date value fetched from the server and let me change it with the date picker.

Surprisingly, all other columns of the `mat-table` populates fine from the service values apart from this particular input date field.

My template snippet:

```
<mat-table class="mat-table-class" matSort [dataSource]="dataSource" #table>
<form #myForm="ngForm">
  <ng-container ...> </ng-container>
  <ng-container ...> </ng-container>
  <ng-container ...> </ng-container>
  <ng-container ...> </ng-container>
  <ng-container class="form-group" matColumnDef="dueDate">
    <mat-header-cell ....></mat-header-cell>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width:150px">
                <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="date"
                  name="dueDate" #dueDate="ngModel"
                  class="form-control" [ngModel]="element.dueDate"
                  autocomplete="off"  
                  (ngModelChange)="onDueDateChanges($event, element); 
                          element.dueDate = $event"/>
              </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>
   .......
<form>
</mat-table>
```

My component snippet:

```
getGridData()
{
   this.myService.getGridDataAsync(...)
     .subscribe((data: any)=> {
        if (data && data.isSuccess) {
          this.dataSource.data = data.responseObject;
          this.dataSource.data.forEach((entry: any) => {
          if(entry.dueDate){
             entry.dueDate = this.datePipe.transform(entry.dueDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'); // transforming to string in 'yyyy-MM-dd' format
      }
     });
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I feel your "entry.dueDate" is a "string", not a "Date object", so you can not use datePipeTransform. Check it adding `console.log(entry.dueDate)` in your function.

Comment: @Eliseo I've checked, it's a Date object all, it prints a Date with timestamp